# ruby on rails undefined method for array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user who owns many phones
I have a a phone which has many call summaries
therefore my user has many call summaries

Now to the code that I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :phones
    has_many :call_summaries, :through => :phones
end  

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :call_summaries
end

class CallSummary < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :phones
end
```

I would like to generate a report that shows all the call summaries for the phones that belong to that certain user. I go into the controller and this is my code there:

```
def index
  @phones = Phone.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", @current_user.id])
  @call_summaries = @phones.call_summaries.find(:all)
end
```

But this is returning this error:

> undefined method `call_summaries' for #Array:0x476d2d0

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the has_many :through relationship set up, you should just be able to do:

```
@call_summaries = @current_user.call_summaries
```

The problem with your method is that you're calling `call_summaries` on the @phones collection, rather than on individual phone instances.

Comment: Ah this worked, thanks. Just one more thing, I set up a foreign key in call_summaries because the column names are different. And I am not looking for the phones.id column either. I am looking for a generated hex key. This is the SQL that is generated from the correct command with a foreign key:

SELECT call_summaries.* FROM call_summaries INNER JOIN phones ON call_summaries.reported_by = phones.id 
WHERE phones.user_id = 1

It should be phones.hex_key instead of phones.id. How do I change that, I tried foreign keys but unless i did something dumb, that didn't work. 

Thanks again!

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to use the :foreign_key and :primary_key options on both ends of the association. In CallSummary, for instance, try `belongs_to :phone, :foreign_key => :reported_by, :primary_key => :hex_key` (and do the same thing for the has_many association in Phone).

Answer (score 2):

`@phones` is an array of `Phone` objects.  You have to iterate through that array and add each phone's call summaries to a single array.  Try this:

```
@phones = Phone.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", @current_user.id])
@call_summaries = @phones.inject([]){|arr, phone| arr + phone.call_summaries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Off topic and just me being fussy, but a dynamic finder is more readable:

```
@phones = Phone.find_all_by_user_id(@current_user)
```

Comment: should be `@phones = Phone.find_all_by_user_id(@current_user.id)`